# Generating Java Classes dynamically from an XML document

Tags: java, xml, reflection

Consider this scenario: I've an XML file called person.xml with the following data in it.

```
<person>
    <name>MrFoo</name>
    <age>28</age>
</person>
```

If I want to read this XML into a Java object, I would be creating a Java bean called PersonBean (with getters/setters for the attributes) as:

```
class Person{
    String name;
    int age;
}
```

And I could use any APIs for reading the XML and populating the Java Bean.

But the real question here is, suppose if the structure of the XML file changes, i.e. if an new attribute 'email' is added to the XML file, then I have to modify the Java Bean also to add a new attribute. But, I want to avoid changing the Java code even if the XML structure changes.

So, what I'm trying to do is, I'm creating another XML file called PersonStructure.xml with the content as:

```
<class name="Person">
  <attributes>
      <attribute>
          <name>personName</name>
          <type>java.lang.String</type>
      </attribute>
      ... and it goes like this...
   </attribute>
</class>
```

Is it possible to read the PersonStructure.XML file and convert it into Person.Java class file? The approach what I'm trying to do is correct or is there any other way to do the same?

Comment: one minor question, what would your java code do your new changed object? wouldn't you have to adapt your business code anyway to use the new version of the beans?

Comment: Is the title of your question correct? It sounds like you want to generate java objects, not java classes.

Comment: I want to create Java class structure from the XML file. :)

Comment: @Nuno

This XML parsing will be a part of a huge web application and the XML structure may change in future. So, to avoid re-deploying the entire web application even for a small change, I'm trying this approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While this is not exactly what you are trying to do, you should have a look at JAXB. It can generate a set of Java classes from a Schema definition. Your PersonStructure.xml file looks quite a bit like an XSD with a different syntax, so you could reuse JAXB.

https://jaxb.dev.java.net/

Comment: You can also use XMLBeans which does nearly the same as JAXB http://xmlbeans.apache.org/

Answer (score 4):

Not very familiar with Java (I'm mostly a .NET guy), but common sense applies: there's actually very little use in dynamically generated beans (unless you'll be binding those to some control, in which case array of `Object`s will do just fine).

What is more logical is codegen'ing Java beans from this XML definitions, which can be done with [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT).

PS. Do not try to make a programming language out of XML. Hell will definitely break loose if you do so.

Answer (score 0):

I am running through somehow more or less the same problem (I need to transform data in Java to a POM.xml file), one of the things that did not work for me, but maybe could work for you was the XStream library, it transforms java classes into xml, you should take a look:

http://x-stream.github.io/

I am in anyway related to them, just a random guy looking for his own answers. Should you have any questions about how to use this library you should try to contact them.
Hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to accommodate possible new fields, a Map would be more useful for you than a class.

Illustrating using your example, instead of this:

```
Person person = getPersonFromSomewhere();
System.out.printf("%s was %d years old\n", person.name, person.age);
person.age++; // happy birthday!
```

... you'd do this:

```
Map<String, Object> person = getPersonFromSomewhere();
System.out.printf("%s was %d years old\n", person.get("name"), person.get("age"));
int currentAge = (Integer) person.get("age"); // real code would sanitise the value first
person.put("age", currentAge + 1); // happy birthday!
```

Yes, it means more code and less error checking (the compiler won't tell you if you misspell 'name' and there's no type checking), but it would do what you want. And considering best practice is to code getters and setters instead of accessing member fields directly, in real life you'd be writing more code anyhow.

If you decide to go this route, refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537207/how-to-convert-xml-to-java-util-map-and-vice-versa) for how to convert to/from XML.