# How to convert XML to java.util.Map and vice versa?

Tags: java, xml

I'm searching a lightweight API (preferable single class) to convert a

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String();
```

to XML and, vice versa, convert the XML back to a `Map<String,String>`.

example:

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String();
map.put("name","chris");
map.put("island","faranga");

MagicAPI.toXML(map,"root");
```

result:

```
<root>
  <name>chris</chris>
  <island>faranga</island>
</root>
```

and back:

```
Map<String,String> map = MagicAPI.fromXML("...");
```

I don't want to use [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/) or [JSON conversion API](http://json.org/java/). It doesn't have to take care of nested maps or attributes or anything else, just that simple case.
Any suggestions?

---

I created a working copy & paste sample. Thanks to [fvu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112079/fvu) and [Michal Bernhard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70786/michal-bernhard).

[Download latest XStream framework](http://xstream.codehaus.org/download.html), 'core only' is enough.

```
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
map.put("name","chris");
map.put("island","faranga");

// convert to XML
XStream xStream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
xStream.alias("map", java.util.Map.class);
String xml = xStream.toXML(map);

// from XML, convert back to map
Map<String,Object> map2 = (Map<String,Object>) xStream.fromXML(xml);
```

No converters or anything else is required. Just the [xstream-x.y.z.jar](http://repository.codehaus.org/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.3.1/xstream-1.3.1.jar) is enough.

Comment: With the current version of XStream, the example yields `<map>
  <entry>
    <string>name</string>
    <string>chris</string>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <string>island</string>
    <string>faranga</string>
  </entry>
</map>`

Comment: Well I tested several version from 1.2 (older version failed deserialization/unmarshal part) up to the latest version of 1.4.6 and always there is needed custom map converter like in my answer below to produce output you want. Otherwise it outputs what Arjan says in comment above.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

XStream!

**Updated**: I added unmarshal part as requested in comments..

```
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.Converter;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.MarshallingContext;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.UnmarshallingContext;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.HierarchicalStreamReader;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.HierarchicalStreamWriter;

import java.util.AbstractMap;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        map.put("name","chris");
        map.put("island","faranga");

        XStream magicApi = new XStream();
        magicApi.registerConverter(new MapEntryConverter());
        magicApi.alias("root", Map.class);

        String xml = magicApi.toXML(map);
        System.out.println("Result of tweaked XStream toXml()");
        System.out.println(xml);

        Map<String, String> extractedMap = (Map<String, String>) magicApi.fromXML(xml);
        assert extractedMap.get("name").equals("chris");
        assert extractedMap.get("island").equals("faranga");

    }

    public static class MapEntryConverter implements Converter {

        public boolean canConvert(Class clazz) {
            return AbstractMap.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
        }

        public void marshal(Object value, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {

            AbstractMap map = (AbstractMap) value;
            for (Object obj : map.entrySet()) {
                Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) obj;
                writer.startNode(entry.getKey().toString());
                Object val = entry.getValue();
                if ( null != val ) {
                    writer.setValue(val.toString());
                }
                writer.endNode();
            }

        }

        public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {

            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            while(reader.hasMoreChildren()) {
                reader.moveDown();

                String key = reader.getNodeName(); // nodeName aka element's name
                String value = reader.getValue();
                map.put(key, value);

                reader.moveUp();
            }

            return map;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: well, it works without a converter too, but u are right, thats it

Comment: XStream xs = new XStream(new DomDriver("UTF-8", new XmlFriendlyReplacer("_-", "\_"))); // for proper underscores handling

Comment: I had tried the above code in case where map has domain objects,String,Boolean etc but not converting to xml,  can you suggest what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for this response. I am trying to unmarshal the `XML` and I am not getting how to implement the `unmarshal` method here. if possible can you please provide and example for `unmarshal` method mentioned within the `MapAdapter` class: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32483762/7584240

Answer (score 44):

Here the converter for XStream including unmarshall

```
public class MapEntryConverter implements Converter{
public boolean canConvert(Class clazz) {
    return AbstractMap.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
}

public void marshal(Object value, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {
    AbstractMap<String,String> map = (AbstractMap<String,String>) value;
    for (Entry<String,String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        writer.startNode(entry.getKey().toString());
        writer.setValue(entry.getValue().toString());
        writer.endNode();
    }
}

public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    while(reader.hasMoreChildren()) {
        reader.moveDown();
        map.put(reader.getNodeName(), reader.getValue());
        reader.moveUp();
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: Man, I've had to write this stupid converter 500 times now. You would say I'd learn! *Every* single time I have to knock up a weirder represented map, I end up seeing your answer. I'd plus ten you if I could! ;)

Answer (score 8):

How about [XStream](https://x-stream.github.io/)?  Not 1 class but 2 jars for many use cases including yours, very simple to use yet quite  powerful.

Answer (score 8):

One option would be to roll your own. It would be fairly simple to do:

```
Document doc = getDocument();
Element root = doc.createElement(rootName);
doc.appendChild(root);
for (Map.Entry<String,String> element : map.entrySet() ) {
    Element e = doc.createElement(element.getKey());
    e.setTextContent(element.getValue());
    root.appendChild(e);
}
save(doc, file);
```

and the load is an equally simply `getChildNodes` and a loop. Sure it has a bit of boiler plate that the XML Gods demand but it is at most 1 hours work.

Or you could look at [Properties](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#storeToXML%28java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) if you are not too fused about the format of the XML.

Comment: does this function sort the xml?I am trying to build a func to sort xml alphabetically according to one element

Answer (score 6):

I used the approach with the custom converter:

```
public static class MapEntryConverter implements Converter {

    public boolean canConvert(Class clazz) {
        return AbstractMap.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    public void marshal(Object value, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {

        AbstractMap map = (AbstractMap) value;
        for (Object obj : map.entrySet()) {
            Entry entry = (Entry) obj;
            writer.startNode(entry.getKey().toString());
            context.convertAnother(entry.getValue());
            writer.endNode();
        }
    }

    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {
        // dunno, read manual and do it yourself ;)
    }

}
```

But i changed the the serialization of the maps value to delegate to the MarshallingContext. This should improve the solution to work for composite map values and nested maps as well.

Comment: This would be a better example if `unmarshal()` were complete.

Answer (score 4):

I found this on google, but I don't want to use XStream, because it causes to much overhead in my environment. I only needed to parse a file and since I did not find anything I like I created my own simple solution for parsing a file of the format that you describe. So here is my solution:

```
public class XmlToMapUtil {
    public static Map<String, String> parse(InputSource inputSource) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {
        final DataCollector handler = new DataCollector();
        SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser().parse(inputSource, handler);
        return handler.result;
    }

    private static class DataCollector extends DefaultHandler {
        private final StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        private final Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();

        @Override
        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
            final String value = buffer.toString().trim();
            if (value.length() > 0) {
                result.put(qName, value);
            }
            buffer.setLength(0);
        }

        @Override
        public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
            buffer.append(ch, start, length);
        }
    }
}
```

Here are a couple of TestNG+FEST Assert Tests:

```
public class XmlToMapUtilTest {

    @Test(dataProvider = "provide_xml_entries")
    public void parse_returnsMapFromXml(String xml, MapAssert.Entry[] entries) throws Exception {
        // execution
        final Map<String, String> actual = XmlToMapUtil.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));

        // evaluation
        assertThat(actual)
            .includes(entries)
            .hasSize(entries.length);
    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] provide_xml_entries() {
        return new Object[][]{
                {"<root />", new MapAssert.Entry[0]},

                {
                    "<root><a>aVal</a></root>", new MapAssert.Entry[]{
                            MapAssert.entry("a", "aVal")
                    },
                },

                {
                    "<root><a>aVal</a><b>bVal</b></root>", new MapAssert.Entry[]{
                            MapAssert.entry("a", "aVal"),
                            MapAssert.entry("b", "bVal")
                    },
                },

                {
                    "<root> \t <a>\taVal </a><b /></root>", new MapAssert.Entry[]{
                            MapAssert.entry("a", "aVal")
                    },
                },
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer, and much lighter weight than XStream. XStream was also creating version errors in Android with Robolectric, which also relies on XStream, where as that can be avoided with this version. Note that this code does not insert empty nodes like `<empty />`, while the XStream example inserts them as empty strings. This can be modified using `startNode()` to save the name of the first node and then removing the `> 0` check.

Answer (score 4):

I have written a piece of code that transforms a XML content into a multi-layer structure of maps:

```
public static Object convertNodesFromXml(String xml) throws Exception {

    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = db.parse(is);
    return createMap(document.getDocumentElement());
}

public static Object createMap(Node node) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node currentNode = nodeList.item(i);
        String name = currentNode.getNodeName();
        Object value = null;
        if (currentNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            value = createMap(currentNode);
        }
        else if (currentNode.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            return currentNode.getTextContent();
        }
        if (map.containsKey(name)) {
            Object os = map.get(name);
            if (os instanceof List) {
                ((List<Object>)os).add(value);
            }
            else {
                List<Object> objs = new LinkedList<Object>();
                objs.add(os);
                objs.add(value);
                map.put(name, objs);
            }
        }
        else {
            map.put(name, value);
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

This code transforms this:

```
<house>
    <door>blue</door>
    <living-room>
        <table>wood</table>
        <chair>wood</chair>
    </living-room>
</house>
```

into

```
{
    "house": {
        "door": "blue",
        "living-room": {
            "table": "wood",
            "chair": "wood"
        }
     }
 }
```

I don't have the inverse process, but that must not be very difficult to write.

Comment: This code does not produce the Map the OP says that it does

Comment: Underscore-java can convert in both directions. Just use methods U.xmlToJson() and U.jsonToXml().

Answer (score 4):

[Underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) library can convert Map to xml. [Live example](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/x2h)

Code example:

```
import com.github.underscore.U;
import java.util.*;
    
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("name", "chris");
    map.put("island", "faranga");

    System.out.println(U.toXml(map));

    //  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    //  <root>
    //    <name>chris</name>
    //    <island>faranga</island>
    //  </root>

    // and back:
    map = U.fromXmlMap("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><root>"
        + "    <name>chris</name>"
        + "    <island>faranga</island>"
        + "  </root>");
        
    System.out.println(map);
    // {name=chris, island=faranga}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am posting this as an answer not because it's the correct answer to your question, but because it's a solution to the same problem, but using attributes instead. Otherwise Vikas Gujjar's answer is correct.

Quite oftern your data could be in attributes, but it's quite hard to find any working examples using XStream to do this, so here's one:

Sample data:

```
<settings>
    <property name="prop1" value="foo"/>
    <property name="prop2" /> <!-- NOTE:
                                   The example supports null elements as
                                   the backing object is a HashMap.
                                   A Properties object would be handled
                                   by a PropertiesConverter which wouldn't
                                   allow you null values.  -->
    <property name="prop3" value="1"/>
</settings>
```

Implementation of MapEntryConverter (slightly re-worked @Vikas Gujjar's implementation to use attributes instead):

```
public class MapEntryConverter
        implements Converter
{

    public boolean canConvert(Class clazz)
    {
        return AbstractMap.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    public void marshal(Object value,
                        HierarchicalStreamWriter writer,
                        MarshallingContext context)
    {
        //noinspection unchecked
        AbstractMap<String, String> map = (AbstractMap<String, String>) value;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet())
        {
            //noinspection RedundantStringToString
            writer.startNode(entry.getKey().toString());
            //noinspection RedundantStringToString
            writer.setValue(entry.getValue().toString());
            writer.endNode();
        }
    }

    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader,
                            UnmarshallingContext context)
    {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        while (reader.hasMoreChildren())
        {
            reader.moveDown();
            map.put(reader.getAttribute("name"), reader.getAttribute("value"));
            reader.moveUp();
        }

        return map;
    }
}
```

XStream instance setup, parsing and storing:

```
    XStream xstream = new XStream();
    xstream.autodetectAnnotations(true);
    xstream.alias("settings", HashMap.class);
    xstream.registerConverter(new MapEntryConverter());
    ...
    // Parse:
    YourObject yourObject = (YourObject) xstream.fromXML(is);
    // Store:
    xstream.toXML(yourObject);
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried different kinds of maps and the [Conversion Box](http://capsulesforthejavamind.blogspot.in/2015/01/conversion-box.html) worked. I have used your map and have pasted an example below with some inner maps. Hope it is helpful to you ....

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import cjm.component.cb.map.ToMap;
import cjm.component.cb.xml.ToXML;

public class Testing
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>(); // ORIGINAL MAP

        map.put("name", "chris");
        map.put("island", "faranga");

        Map<String, String> mapInner = new HashMap<String, String>(); // SAMPLE INNER MAP

        mapInner.put("a", "A");
        mapInner.put("b", "B");
        mapInner.put("c", "C");

        map.put("innerMap", mapInner);

        Map<String, Object> mapRoot = new HashMap<String, Object>(); // ROOT MAP

        mapRoot.put("ROOT", map);

        System.out.println("Map: " + mapRoot);

        System.out.println();

        ToXML toXML = new ToXML();

        String convertedXML = String.valueOf(toXML.convertToXML(mapRoot, true)); // CONVERTING ROOT MAP TO XML

        System.out.println("Converted XML: " + convertedXML);

        System.out.println();

        ToMap toMap = new ToMap();

        Map<String, Object> convertedMap = toMap.convertToMap(convertedXML); // CONVERTING CONVERTED XML BACK TO MAP

        System.out.println("Converted Map: " + convertedMap);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Output:

```
Map: {ROOT={name=chris, innerMap={b=B, c=C, a=A}, island=faranga}}

 -------- Map Detected -------- 
 -------- XML created Successfully -------- 
Converted XML: <ROOT><name>chris</name><innerMap><b>B</b><c>C</c><a>A</a></innerMap><island>faranga</island></ROOT>

 -------- XML Detected -------- 
 -------- Map created Successfully -------- 
Converted Map: {ROOT={name=chris, innerMap={b=B, c=C, a=A}, island=faranga}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Now it's 2017, The latest version of XStream requires a converter to make it works as your expected.

A converter supports nested map:

```
public class MapEntryConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public void marshal(Object value, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext marshallingContext) {
        AbstractMap map = (AbstractMap) value;
        for (Object obj : map.entrySet()) {
            Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) obj;
            writer.startNode(entry.getKey().toString());
            Object val = entry.getValue();
            if (val instanceof Map) {
                marshal(val, writer, marshallingContext);
            } else if (null != val) {
                writer.setValue(val.toString());
            }
            writer.endNode();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext unmarshallingContext) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

        while(reader.hasMoreChildren()) {
            reader.moveDown();

            String key = reader.getNodeName(); // nodeName aka element's name
            String value = reader.getValue().replaceAll("\\n|\\t", "");
            if (StringUtils.isBlank(value)) {
                map.put(key, unmarshal(reader, unmarshallingContext));
            } else {
                map.put(key, value);
            }

            reader.moveUp();
        }

        return map;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canConvert(Class clazz) {
        return AbstractMap.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the best answer yet. But it does not support iterables

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to convert simple map to xml, without nested properties, then the lightweight solution would be just a private method, as follows:

```
private String convertMapToXML(Map<String, String> map) {
    StringBuilder xmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    xmlBuilder.append("<xml>");
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue() != null) {
            String xmlElement = entry.getKey();
            xmlBuilder.append("<");
            xmlBuilder.append(xmlElement);
            xmlBuilder.append(">");
            xmlBuilder.append(entry.getValue());
            xmlBuilder.append("<");
            xmlBuilder.append("/");
            xmlBuilder.append(xmlElement);                
            xmlBuilder.append(">");
        }             
    }

    xmlBuilder.append("</xml>");
    return xmlBuilder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I convert DBresponse to XML in Camel ctx.
JDBC executor return the ArrayList (rows)  with LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap (single row). 
Task - create XML object based on DBResponce.

```
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

public class ConvertDBToXMLProcessor implements Processor {

    public void process(List body) {

        if (body instanceof ArrayList) {
            ArrayList<LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap> rows = (ArrayList) body;

            DocumentBuilder builder = null;
            builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = builder.newDocument();
            Element rootElement = document.createElement("DBResultSet");

            for (LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap row : rows) {
                Element newNode = document.createElement("Row");
                row.forEach((key, value) -> {
                    if (value != null) {
                        Element newKey = document.createElement((String) key);
                        newKey.setTextContent(value.toString());
                        newNode.appendChild(newKey);
                    }
                });
                rootElement.appendChild(newNode);
            }
            document.appendChild(rootElement);


            /* 
            * If you need return string view instead org.w3c.dom.Document
            */
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
            DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(document);
            TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
            transformer.transform(domSource, result);

            // return document
            // return writer.toString()

        }
    }
}
```