# Android ListView using a key-value map type structure possible?

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView which is populated from a string-array resource. I'm trying to figure out how I can use a key-value type of structure, so that the key is displayed in the ListView, and when a row is selected I can get the value.

I know I could maintain a separate array for the values and do a lookup using the selected index of the row but this is hard to maintain.

Also I think I could make a POJO and build the list with those objects with my own custom list adaptor, but I want to just use a simple xml file if possible.

I'm reading the documentation to see if I can do this in xml but I've not found anything like this yet?

Thanks for you time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just created a bunch of POJOs and used a custom list adapter to display the relevant data from the Object in the List Row.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the Map that is ordered such as [TreeMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TreeMap.html) or [LinkedHashMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) and pass it to your adapter.

This would enable what you are trying to achieve.

You basically need to have an adapter that utilize the Key-Value pair data structure (Map) and set it in your list view, something like:

```
public class OrderedMapAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        Map.Entry[]  entries;

        /***
         * Pass the key value pair map using an ordered map data structure
         * @param orderedMap An ordered map, either LinkedHashMap or TreeMap
         */
        public OrderedMapAdapter(LinkedHashMap orderedMap) {
            this.entries = orderedMap.entrySet().toArray(new Map.Entry[0]);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return entries.length;
        }

        /***
         * This should get you the position you want in Key-value pair format
         * that you could use whenever the row is selected
         */
        public Map.Entry getItem(int position) {
            return entries[position];
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // display your view here
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure you've read my question correctly, I'm not asking about what Java type to use. I'm asking about how to declare a Map in XML and use it in my ListView.

Comment: Hmm I might have. When you say string-array resource, are you saying strings.xml that you want to put in ListView?

Comment: Nope, when I say string-array I'm just describing what I have done so far and how I want to actually do something that is a bit different, asI describe afterwards. Anyway, there isn't a built in 'android' way to do it so I'm doing it with static arrays.

Comment: Then I think I am answering the correct thing. You just need to create your own extension of BaseAdapter and use an ordered Map like I mention above as a data structure (as they are structured as key-value pair already). I could put up a skeleton code if you like.

Comment: Yeah I know, that was one of the options I have already mentioned, map of POJOs with my own adapter or maintain two arrays. Again, my question was asking if I can do it simply in android in XML rather than in Java. And by that I don't mean read and parse the XML myself, I mean use the Android framework, but alas, it's not supported.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your second suggestion using a custom list adapter is going to be the easiest solution for what you want to do.

The SimpleAdapter drives the XML file approach you mentioned and is quite particular on the format of data it receives. If you can restructure the format of your input data to match, the SimpleAdapter will work fine.

Otherwise use the ArrayAdapter and a POJO, and build the list required for your implementation.

Comment: It appears that there isn't an 'android' way of doing this. I'll have to either parse my own XML in to a map or just build the Map in code, grrr.

Comment: You could get XStream to do a lot of the work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537207/how-to-convert-xml-to-java-util-map-and-vice-versa. I've not tried XStream in Android but their documentation suggests it works, depends on whether you can afford the extra jar dependency...