# How to override XStream MapConverter

Tags: xstream

Plz tell me how can i override MapConverter in XStream. How can I regoster it with XStream. Its not working in my case.

Comment: Please have a look at this [answer][1]<br/>


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537207/how-to-convert-xml-to-java-util-map-and-vice-versa