# Java: Generating XML sheet from template and dictionary

Tags: java, xml, templates

So basically I've been trying to figure this out for a little while, here's the problem:

I have an `XML` template file, whether it be an `XSLT` or something different isn't a problem to me since the templates haven't been created yet. But I'm curious how I would take, for example, a dictionary object and fill in the blanks of an `XML` template with their values.

EXAMPLE:

Let's say I have a pseudo code dictionary:

```
dict = { "name" : "bob" , 
         "age"  : "100" }
```

and some kind of `XML` template:

```
<person>
     <name></name>
     <age></age>
</person>
```

How would I go about, in Java, generating an `XML` sheet that looks like this:

```
<person>
      <name>bob</name>
      <age>100</age>
</person>
```

Again, I am not looking for a super specific answer as I am a capable coder, I was more wondering what a good methodology for doing this is? Is there a good library? Are `XLST`'s the way to go? and if so where would I go to learn about Java's interaction with them?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Your pseudo code dictionary looks like JSON. You could load JSON to a Java object that would have name and age properties with libraries like Jackson or GSON, and store object to XML with
any of Java XML libraries (for simple cases i like XStream - take a look at this question: [How to convert XML to java.util.Map and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537207/how-to-convert-xml-to-java-util-map-and-vice-versa))