# Convert XML/SOAP to Maps in Community edition

Tags: mule

I know Datamapper can easily convert an XML structure to a map easily. But what is the best way to do this in Community edition? Note I want Maps rather than a concrete class sung Jaxb.

The json-to-object-transformer allows you to easily convert to a map but is there anything similar for XML?

Comment: xml-to-object-transformer?

Answer (score 0):

As of now Mule Community Edition doesn't provide any out of the box solution for this.

You can always crate a Custom transformer and use some API like XStream to convert the XML to map.

Following Stackoverflow post give you a sample of how to use XStream API.
[How to convert XML to java.util.Map and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537207/how-to-convert-xml-to-java-util-map-and-vice-versa)

Hope this helps.