# Convert XML String to Map and get the key & value pairs using Java

Tags: java, xml, dictionary, xstream

I have an XML String. I'm trying to convert that string into map so that I can get key & value. However its not able to convert. Here is my code

```
String xmlString = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><user>
                        <kyc></kyc>
                        <address></address>
                        <resiFI></resiFI></user>"

def convertStringToDocument = {
        xmlString ->
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder;
            try {
                builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
                org.w3c.dom.Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));
                return doc;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
    }
    def populateDocProofsFromWaiversXML = {
        xmlString, mandateFlag ->

            final List<DocumentProof> documentProofs = new ArrayList<DocumentProof>();
            if (xmlString != null) {
                try {
                    HashMap<String, String> values = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    Document xml = convertStringToDocument(waiversList);
                    org.w3c.dom.Node user = xml.getFirstChild();
                    NodeList childs = user.getChildNodes();
                    org.w3c.dom.Node child;
                    for (int i = 0; i < childs.getLength(); i++) {
                        child = childs.item(i);
                        System.out.println(child.getNodeName());
                        System.out.println(child.getNodeValue());
                        values.put(child.getNodeName(), child.getNodeValue());
                    }
                }  catch (Throwable t) {
                    println "error"
                    //LOG.error("Could not set document proofs from waivers ", t);
                }
            }
            return documentProofs;
    }
```

I'd like to get "kyc" as key and the respective value. Any better ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537207/how-to-convert-xml-to-java-util-map-and-vice-versa

Comment: try to use dom xml parser

Comment: @virendrao, Can you plz provide a snippet of example?

Comment: @Nizam check below answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
package com.test;

import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class Random {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, String> values = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String xmlString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><user><kyc>123</kyc><address>test</address><resiFI>asds</resiFI></user>";
        Document xml = convertStringToDocument(xmlString);
        Node user = xml.getFirstChild();
        NodeList childs = user.getChildNodes();
        Node child;
        for (int i = 0; i < childs.getLength(); i++) {
            child = childs.item(i);
            System.out.println(child.getNodeName());
            System.out.println(child.getTextContent());
            values.put(child.getNodeName(), child.getTextContent());
        }

    }

    private static Document convertStringToDocument(String xmlStr) {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder;
        try {
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(
                    xmlStr)));
            return doc;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This will work. Please check :)
You can play with DOM.

Comment: It says "Could not find matching constructor for: java.io.StringReader(com.pramati.org.apache.xerces.dom.DeferredElementImpl)" at this line "Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader("

Comment: @Nizam are imports of class same for StringReader ? which version java you have ? i have this code running on 1.5

Comment: I'm using 1.7 java version

Comment: are imports proper in code i posted and what you are running? can you just copy paste above code in ide and try to run

Comment: Please send your email.. I'll send you the code there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90420/discussion-between-virendrao-and-nizam).

Comment: I've pinged you. Can you please respond it there

Comment: I'm getting the key & values as Node:panVerifiedFlag
Value:null
Node:#text
Value:

Comment: @Nizam because your node value for tag is null

Comment: I've pinged you. Can we discuss in chat