# How can we convert nested multi level Map to XML in Java?

Tags: java, xml

I tried to do in way that is in below link

[How to convert XML to java.util.Map and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537207/how-to-convert-xml-to-java-util-map-and-vice-versa)

But this is not going all over the Map.

Please Advise!

Comment: I advise to not write such unclear / unspecific / broad questions. At least limit the question to one xml API and include a example with input/desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `XmlAdapter` and override `marshal` and `unmarshal` method.
Here is example code show how to convert `Map<String,Boolean>` to XML and vice versa:

```
public class MapAdapter extends XmlAdapter<MapElements[], Map<String, Boolean>> {

  public MapAdapter() {
  }

  @Override
  public MapElements[] marshal(Map<String, Boolean> v) throws Exception {
    MapElements[] elements = new MapElements[v.size()];
    int i = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<String, Boolean> entry : v.entrySet()) {
        elements[i++] = new MapElements(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    return elements;
  }

  @Override
  public Map<String, Boolean> unmarshal(MapElements[] v) throws Exception {
    Map<String, Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (MapElements element : v) {
        map.put(element.key, element.value);
    }
    return map;
  }

}

 class MapElements {

   @XmlElement
   public String key;
   @XmlElement
   public Boolean value;

   public MapElements() {
   }

   public MapElements(String key, Boolean value) {
      this.key = key;
      this.value = value;
   }

 }
```

and use `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation on `Map<String,Boolean>` field as follow

```
 @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MapAdapter.class)
 private Map<String, Boolean> map
```

Comment: How can you be sure jaxb is used or even known to the OP?