# How to increment @XmlElement name in list element in java springboot

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, file, xml-parsing

`This output I need to achieved:

```
<Entity>
<MRA_BALANCE_SHEET>
       <R0030C0030>value</R0030C0030>
       <R0030C0040>value</R0030C0040>
</MRA_BALANCE_SHEET>
<MRA_BALANCE_SHEET>
       <R0040C0030>value</R0040C0030>
       <R0040C0040>value</R0040C0030>
</MRA_BALANCE_SHEET>
</Entity>
```

every element, the "R0030" will increment by 10. so as you can see in the next list the R0030C0030 will increment by 10, =  "R0040C0030"

need help`

and this is my sample entity

```
        private String PHP;
        private String PHPUSD;
        
        
        @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DynamicElementNameAdapter.class)
        public String getPHP() {
            return PHP;
        }

         /setter...
```

I already tried this adapter

```
    public class DynamicElementNameAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, String>{

     private static int counter = 30;
     
    @Override
    public String unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(String v) throws Exception {
            
            String dynamicElementName = "R" + String.format("%04d", counter) + "C0030";
            counter += 10; // Increment by 10 for the next element
            return dynamicElementName;
    }

}
```

but the output is wrong :

```
<Entity>
<MRA_BALANCE_SHEET>
       <PHP>R0030C0030</PHP>
</MRA_BALANCE_SHEET>
<MRA_BALANCE_SHEET>
       <PHP>R0040C0030</PHP>
</MRA_BALANCE_SHEET>
</Entity>
```

HELP!!!

Comment: Too less detail. How are you generating your XML document?

Comment: from excel to xml . conversion, I need to increment the XmlElement name , by 10

Comment: Everything can be done easily with a Powershell script.

Comment: what is powershell script? how ? thanks

Comment: As far as I understand, XmlAdapter works on value, not element. So, while you can change the value through your adapter (which it is already doing), you can't change element name. Better to use some collection instead.

Comment: how? do you have some ideas? thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should create a map of your element name as key and element value as value. Then, you can use XStream or any other library to convert this map to xml.

See [How to convert XML to java.util.Map and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537207/how-to-convert-xml-to-java-util-map-and-vice-versa) for more info.

Comment: I'm using marshaler for convertion (excel to xml)

Comment: You can use solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/32483762/841221